# How to choose an appropriate N-FET for a BMS?

Tags: batteries, bms

I am drawing an schematic for a battery management system (BMS) based on the [BQ76920](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76920.pdf?ts=1678426793611&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ76920) and I have trouble with the N-channel FETs. How could I know an appropriate part?

This is the schematic:

[image]

I am following the datasheet design guide and it says something about voltage and current but I am confused what is that value in the N-FET datasheet.

This is the text of the design guide:

[image]

In a [github project](https://github.com/ceech/BQ76920-BMS/blob/master/Schematic_01.png) that is based in the same chip (BQ76920), the developer uses the PSMN7R0-100BS, but I want to know the considerations to pick another one for reasons such as availability in stock.

[image]

The datasheet of the PSMN7R0-100BS is [here](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSMN7R0-100BS.pdf) How could I know that the PSMN7R0-100BS N-FET is appropriate?

[image]

Comment: Voltage is VDS; current is ID (but also check the graphs section); power is Ptot (but also check your thermal design)

Comment: I assume you're looking for an *appropriate* (i.e. fitting for the application) part, not an *appropriated* (i.e. stolen or otherwise taken without permission) part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider how the MOSFETs are used in the application. They are not switched continuously like in a SMPS, but are used more like a load switch. So dynamic characteristics are less important.

The drain-source voltage rating VDS should be higher than your maximum battery stack voltage and leave some margin for transients. The datasheet suggests 10 V per battery cell, so a minimum VDS requirement of 50 V for the five cells in your schematic.

You also need to consider the maximum current of your application. The current through the MOSFETs will lead to power dissipation of:
$$P=R_{DSon} I^2$$
This will heat up the MOSFETs. Depending on the FET package, you will probably need a heat sink for P > 1 W. Look into thermal resistance (Rth,jc and Rth,ja) if you want to know more. For the linked MOSFET a thermal resistance junction-ambient of 60 K/W is given, meaning 60 degrees temperature rise at 1 W power which is already quite significant.

I would also consider the gate drive voltage that is used. The voltage on REGSRC is used for the gate drive. If REGSRC > 12 V, the gate drive voltage will be limited to 12 V. Pretty much all silicon FETs should be fine with 12 V VGS.